# IN Power BI I want to add a dynamic column to a date table where the most recent month is 1 so June = 1 is this possible? thank you

Tags: powerbi

I want to add a dynamic column to a date table where the most recent month is 1 so June = 1 and it goes descending from there (please see image below).. is this possible? thank you

[image: Month with Dynamic Number value]

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to achieve ?

Indeed, you could use automatic time intelligence in Power BI.

For example, you can add a calendar date table by using

> =CALENDAR (DATE (2015, 1, 1), DATE (2020, 12, 31))

and then, eventually, create an index for your month :

> "NMOIS"; FORMAT ( [Date]; "MM" )

OR use Power Query => add an index column

Then, order by your "Month Column" with this index. 
On the Desktop, you will filter your slicer as you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem with the above solutions is that the month that is set at 1 needs to change every month. So when it is May .. May = 1, when it is June.. June =1 this also has to apply for every date in June going back 20 years.. if the month is June it will equal 1.. I hope that explains it a bit more.